# "Conflicting types for 'wiperpos'" and "function returns the address of a local variable" I've tried everything i could think of

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

```
float * GetWiperPos(float VCMD) {//user commanded voltage

    float *Wpos = malloc(2*sizeof(float));

    float Vwiper = VCMD / 10;//Voltage at potentiometer wiper output
    unsigned int Wposition = Vwiper * 205;  //wiper position in decimal (from 0-1023)

    float Wpos[2] = {(float)Wposition, Vwiper};//type casting Wposition, as it needs to be a whole number, but i assume has to be a float for the array to be happy?


    return (float *)Wpos;
}
```

I get function returns the address of a local variable on my return line and conflicting types on the array definition. I've tried using static rather than malloc, different ways other people have used malloc, i just don't know what else to do!

I want to return the value Float Vwiper and int Wposition when the function is called

Comment: The code is not well-formed C++ for reasons other than the error messages you are asking about, so I removed the `c++` tag. Please tag only the language you are actually using. C and C++ are different languages. If I am mistaken, replace the `c` tag with `c++`.

Comment: You have two declarations for `Wpos`.  The first is a pointer.  The second is an array.  Either rename or remove one of them.

Comment: Aside: calling malloc() in an embedded project is rarely a good design choice.

Comment: There was a no symbol `wiperpos` mentioned in the title.  If you have tried _"everything you can think of"_ you need to include those attempts or remove the claim.  It is in its own useless and redundant information.  Looks a bit "cargo-cult" to me.  Certainly an I'll advised method of returning two floats.  Consider returning a struct or passing reference parameters. Both floating-point and malloc are I'll advised in any event.

Comment: Consider `Wposition = (VCMD * 205) / 10 ;` It is not clear why you are returning `Vwiper` when it is just `VCMD/10` and VCMD is already known to the caller.  Or why you would cast an integer to a float.

Comment: This is clearly an X-Y problem.  You are asking how to solve a problem with your solution, where you would do better to ask about a more appropriate solution.  One not involving dynamic memory allocation or floating point.

Answer (score 1):

The name `Wpos` is declared twice in the same scope

```
float *Wpos = malloc(2*sizeof(float));
//...
float Wpos[2] = {(float)Wposition, Vwiper};//type casting Wposition, as it needs to be a whole number, but i assume has to be a float for the array to be happy?
```

At first it is declared as a pointer

```
float *Wpos = malloc(2*sizeof(float));
```

and then as an array.

```
float Wpos[2] = {(float)Wposition, Vwiper};//type casting Wposition, as it needs to be a whole number, but i assume has to be a float for the array to be happy?
```

And you may not return a pointer to a local variable. The pointer will be invalid after exiting the function.

```
return (float *)Wpos;
```

It seems you mean something like the following

```
float *Wpos = malloc(2*sizeof(float));

//...

Wpos[0] = Wposition;
Wpos[1] = Vwiper;

return Wpos;
```

That is the declaration of the array is invalid and must be removed.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem you want to solve is how to return two values from your function, pass two pointers into the function, and have it store the two return values through those. e.g.

```
void GetWiperPos(float VCMD, float *pwiper, unsigned int *pposition)
{
    *pwiper = VCMD / 10;//Voltage at potentiometer wiper output
    *pposition = *pwiper * 205;  //wiper position in decimal (from 0-1023)
}

void test_that_func(void)
{
    float wiper;
    unsigned int position;

    GetWiperPos(100, &wiper, &position);
}
```

Calling things like malloc() is not recommended in embedded projects.